# Development environment and debug

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-config-transform

I need to know something.
I have an own project that I want to deploy in a development environment (debug), and this same one I'll deploy it in a production environment (Release).

What I need to know is about the web.config transformation tag

```
<compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
```

I should not write it in the development environment transformation or should I ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should keep the `debug="true"` attribute in development/debug. That way you will get the correct debugging information when testing.

However, typically you will have two transformation files beneath the main Web.config - `Web.Debug.config` and `Web.Release.config`. Only the `Web.Release.config` should contain the transformation for removing the debug attribute.